# multithread access to platform device driver

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, arm

I am currently writing a platform device driver for embedded linux on ARM. What I've noticed is that a multithreaded application from user space can only access the driver one thread at a time, and never simultaneously regardless of separate file access in /dev/* to the driver.

The same driver (with modified probe()) targeted for x86 on PCIe works fine with multithreaded access to its functions.

Any idea why?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you checking on a multi-core CPU?

Comment: yes, it is a dual core arm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually an error in the user space application.